# rv-on-webkittransitionend binding not working

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I have some transition and I want to handle transitionend with rivets.

```
rv-on-transitionend
```

works fine, but I need it to work on iOS 6 also. I've tried to use

```
rv-on-webkittransitionend
```

but its not working. Help please)

Here is fiddle of what I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRxUc/14/